# function $f\in L^1(\mathbb R) \cup L^2(\mathbb R)$ with $\hat{f}=\sin$

Tags: fourier-transform

Is there a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb R) \cup L^2(\mathbb R)$ with $\hat{f}(x)=\sin(x)$? I think yes because the Fourier transform maps a $L^1$ function into $L^\infty (\mathbb R) \cap C^0(\mathbb R)$ and the function $\sin(x)$ is in $L^\infty (\mathbb R) \cap C^0(\mathbb R)$ Is this true?

Comment: "into" is not the same as "onto."

Comment: Any function in the image of the Fourier transform will go to $0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. So nope. It is called the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: @F.Conrad It's not _quite_ that simple, since the Fourier transform of an $L^2$ function need not tend to zero at infinity...

Comment: @F.Conrad Ok, yes it is that simple. I read the problem as asking about $f\in L^1+L^2$, not $L^1\cup L^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact there is no such $f$ in $L^1+L^2$, a stronger result.

> > **Prop.** If $f\in L^1+L^2$ and $\delta>0$ then $\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_A^{A+\delta}\hat f=0$.

Proof: If $f\in L^1$ this follows from Riemann-Lebesgue, while if $f\in L^2$ then $\hat f\in L^2$. Hence for $f\in L^1+L^2$.

Answer (score 2):

No, since $\mathcal{F}(\delta_a) = e^{-2i \pi a}$ in the sense of distributions, it follows that
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\sin) = \tfrac{1}{2i} \mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) = \frac{\delta_{-1/(2\pi)}-\delta_{1/(2\pi)}}{2i}
$$
which is a measure but is not a locally measurable function.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? It is a perfectly valid proof, as any $L^2$ Fourier transform is also a Fourier transform in the sense of distributions. It additionally gives the intuition behind what kind of functions can have a bounded continuous Fourier transform. So I consider it brings a useful point of view to the OP and future viewers.

Comment: My bad, I definitely meant to upvote this but I can’t change it unless the post is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

If such a function $f$ had been in $L^1(\Bbb R)$, then by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma one would have $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \sin(x)=0$, a contradiction! If such a function $f$ had been in $L^2(\Bbb R)$, then by Plancherel theorem one would have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\sin(x)|^2 dx < \infty$, a contradiction!

Comment: This is essentially David C Ullrich's answer though

Comment: @CalvinKhor I haven't seen his answer before posting mine, but if you want I can delete my answer.